# Kernel Error- Producing Tons of them

Tags: kernel

I'm using elementary OS 5.0 Juno & having this error. It slows down the laptop because there are tons of them:

```
19:20:25 fishin kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL083F:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
19:20:25 fishin kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL083F:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
19:20:25 fishin kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL083F:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
19:20:25 fishin kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL083F:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
19:20:25 fishin kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL083F:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
19:20:25 fishin kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL083F:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
19:20:25 fishin kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL083F:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
19:20:25 fishin kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL083F:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
19:20:25 fishin kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL083F:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is useful for you:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784152

i get same error followed with:
Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

if you answer error to google there is a lot people with same error menssage maybe you can find the answer